# How to create an attribute of a specific type in a new class in java?

Tags: java, class, types, attributes

I'm a Java Newbie and my Task is to create a taxi project with driver, passengers, seats and so on...

I am stuck in this point:
Create a class called Taxi which represents a taxi. Because every taxi has a driver, every Taxi object should have a driver attribute (of type Human). Additionally, the Taxi can have passengers who are also represented by Human objects.

My already existing code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Human human1 = new Human("Max", "Mustermann");

    // System.out.println(human1.getForename() + " " + human1.getName());
    System.out.println("This is " + human1 + ".");

    Taxi taxi1 = new Taxi();

    Human driver1 = new
}

}

public class Human {

private String name;
public String forename;

public Human(String forename, String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.forename = forename;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getForename(){
    return forename;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.forename + " " + this.name;
}
}




public class Taxi {


}
```

How to create driver and passengers of type human in the class Taxi?

Thank you.

Comment: I can give you a hint: If you look at your `Human` class, it has a `name` attribute of type `String`. Try to draw the connection from there. I'm reluctant to blatantly give you the solution to what sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public class Taxi {
    private Human driver;//Taxi has a driver
    public Taxi(Human driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

---

```
// in main
Taxi taxi = new Taxi(human1);//pass that driver in constructor
```

Comment: okay thank you very much, really helpful !

Maybe you can help me implement this task: 
Each taxi can transport up to four passengers plus its driver. Humans get into the taxi separately. The Taxi class has the method add(Human x) to add a new passenger. If the taxi is full, the method doesn’t add the passenger. Instead, the following message shall be printed to the console: "..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should avoid mixing `Human` and `Taxi` concepts in your classes. 
`Human` is really too broad. This is fine for biology or philosophy model domain not for taxi model domain.
You have some drivers ? Create a Driver class.
You have some passengers ? Create a Person or a Passenger class.

Separating concepts allow to settle things as the domain is.

Then provide methods in Taxi to fulfill your requirements :

- having a driver
- adding/removing passengers

For example :

```
public class Taxi {
    private Driver driver;
    private List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Taxi(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public addPassenger(Passenger passenger){
        this.passengers.add(passenger);
    }

    public removePassenger(Passenger passenger){
        this.passengers.remove(passenger);
    }
}
```

Here the Taxi instance may only be "driven" by a `Driver` instance and it may "accept" only `Passenger` instances.
If you have only the `Human` class, you are stuck as anybody may drive a taxi.

If the Driver may also be a Passenger, you may replace the Passenger class by a Person class.